# Set Column Names from list - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 7 columns.

The first three columns already have a column name (for example: `['Apple', 'Banana', 'Strawberry']`.

I want to set the other 4 columns names as ones from a list. I have a list with the following 4: `['Square','Round','Circle','Triangle']`

I would like to create a dataframe with 7 columns with the following names: `['Apple','Banana','Strawberry','Square','Round','Circle','Triangle']`. Is this even possible?

Comment: You can rename columns name by passing a list : df.columns = ["name_1", ...., "name_n"]

Comment: Yes, but I woud like to do this dynamically as the list gets updated from time to time and I don't want to keep writing mannually the names

Comment: Then just pass the variables in a list

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you'd just be able to do this:

```
df.columns[3:] = ['Square','Round','Circle','Triangle']
```

But you can't modify the existing index, so you need to assign a whole new one:

```
df.columns = df.columns[:3].tolist() + ['Square','Round','Circle','Triangle']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, a bit of an example of what you can do

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a dataframe with columns a, b

columnNames = ['a','b']
myData = pd.DataFrame(columns=columnNames)

# Append columnNames to existing ones
columnNames += ['c','d']
myData.columns = columnNames

# Rename all columns with new ones
columnNames = ['e','f','g','h']
myData.columns = columnNames
```